# Configuring Rebus sagas with UnitOfWork

Tags: rebus

I'm currently updating my Rebus 0.45 to 0.70.3 and have come across some problems/thoughts regarding configurations of my sagas. Previously I have done the following:

```
var rebusConfigurer = Configure.With(new WindsorContainerAdapter(container))
                               .Logging(l => l.Log4Net()).Transport(t => t.UseMsmqAndGetInputQueueNameFromAppConfig())
                               .MessageOwnership(o => o.FromRebusConfigurationSection())
                               .Sagas(s => s.StoreInSqlServer(() => (SqlConnection)container.Resolve<INHibernateSessionFactory>().CreateSession().Connection, "sagas", "saga_index"))
                               .SpecifyOrderOfHandlers(s => s.Use(new MyMessageHandlerInspector()));
```

Now that I have to use a ConnectionHolder I started wondering if it was possible to use the same UnitOfWorkManager I'm using for my handlers in my sagas as well?
My Handlers are configured as this:

```
rebusConfigurer.Events(e =>
            {
                e.MessageSent += AutomaticallySetTimeToBeReceived;
                e.UncorrelatedMessage += EOnUncorrelatedMessage;
                e.PoisonMessage += EOnPoisonMessage;
                e.AddUnitOfWorkManager(new RebusNHibernateUnitOfWorkManager(container.Resolve<ISessionFactory>()));
            });
```

If it isn't possible to use the same UnitOfWork for both Events and Sagas and I just need it to work as in 0.45 I suspect that I should just do something along these lines:

```
var rebusConfigurer = Configure.With(new WindsorContainerAdapter(container))
                               .Logging(l => l.Log4Net()).Transport(t => t.UseMsmqAndGetInputQueueNameFromAppConfig())
                               .MessageOwnership(o => o.FromRebusConfigurationSection())
                               .Sagas(s => s.StoreInSqlServer(() => ConnectionHolder.ForNonTransactionalWork((SqlConnection)container.Resolve<INHibernateSessionFactory>().CreateSession().Connection), "sagas", "saga_index"))
                               .SpecifyOrderOfHandlers(s => s.Use(new MyMessageHandlerInspector()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration looks right, except one thing: If you have a unit of work, I'm guessing that you use NHibernate to create a transaction as well?

If that is the case, you should be sure to use the `ConnectionHolder.ForTransactionalWork(...)` factory to get the connection holder, and then you can use [this nasty little trick](http://ayende.com/blog/1583/i-hate-this-code) to retrieve the `SqlTransaction` that is wrapped by NHibernate.

Comment: I'm using NHibernate, so I could use that trick to get the transaction. 
Should the Saga and the Handler use the same session or will that result in some strange behavior if one of them fails? Otherwise I'll just use the UnitOfWorkManager to create a new session for the Saga and then get the transaction with the trick, I presume?

Comment: If they use the same, they will do their work in the same database transaction. I can see no reason why it should not just work :)